# how to manage style in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to learn react. I see a lot of style change inside java script so far. As far as I know, the style should onle be managed by css files. But I am not sure this rule also applies to React. What is the best practice for react. For instance, is the following code a clean code, or is changing the style in the React component a smell and need to be refactored? If so, how it could be refactored?

```
“const Color = ({ title, color}) =>
    <section className="color">
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        <div className="color" 
             style={{ backgroundColor: color }}>
        </div>
    </section>”
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to connect external .css file - it's much more clean.
If there is a need to keep styles in .js I would organize the code in that way:

```
const styles = {
color: 'red',
fontSize: '2rem',
backgroundColor: 'forestgreen'
}
```

And I would apply the styles I need just like here:

```
<div style={{color: styles.color, fontSize: styles.fontSize}}></div>
```

Or, If I need to apply all styles:

```
<div style={styles}></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

That is totally depends on our requirement and preferences. Inline styles are concerned with only component they are written into. You can structure css based on your components so it becomes reusable. You can declare your css in to your components in variables as well as in separate asssets directory.

Well it is more about code readability and re-usability. **Webpack** writes your all css/scss in a single file and inject into your `index.html`. You should look into [JSS](http://cssinjs.org/) so you can compile your css and later inject it into your component as props. Anyways there are a lot of resources that you can leverage from.

Comment: Is one of the technique considered as the best practice as the ReactJs community. In the beginning, I just would like to follow best practice that offered by the community. Which one is more wide spread or mostly accepted??

Comment: You should start from writing css in separate files as per your component based. Then move to Scss and later you can choose JSS. @wasabi it all starts by exploring things. You could master it one day. I hope so

Answer (score 1):

You can also use styled components https://www.styled-components.com/

Comment: life is changing fast :)